# React Redux - React side filtering unmount child component on editing when the child component filter field is no more matching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to implement filter functionality in my application and implemented filtering on react side. There is a parent component(AllAdmins) which is connected to redux and gets all the users and displays on the page as a list of users. This page has a dropdown filter to filter the users by status. Each user in the list is a child component(AdminDetails) which has Edit button to edit this specific User. When clicked on the Edit button, the modal(EditAdminModal) is shown where we can edit the Status of the User. On editing the status I am updating the store on onChange event. As soon as the store is updated, and if the filter is no more matching this updated value, this child being edited(AdminDetails) is unmounted and the update modal(EditAdminModal) and the child component(AdminDetails) disappears.

This is correct behavior based on the implementation and I understood that the issue is because the I am filtering based on the props and now the prop of this child is updated in the redux store. I want to know if this is not the correct way of implementing this functionality and is there any other way to achieve this.

I would appreciate it if someone can help, I am stuck since long on this and I am avoiding server side filtering.

**AllAdmins Parent Component**

```
class AllAdmins extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            filter: ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getAdmins();
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        let filteredAdmins = this.props.admins.filter(admin => admin.status.indexOf(this.state.filter)!==-1);
        
        return(
        <div className="top-align">
            {redirectVar}
            <div className="heading py-1">
                <h4 className="font-weight-bold">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i className="fas fa-user"></i> Admin Users</h4>
            </div>
            
            <div className="container-fluid events-below-heading">
                <div className="events-search-section">
                    <h4 className="text-center text-white all-events-heading p-1 mt-2">All Admin Users</h4>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div  class="col-6 col-sm-2 order-sm-3">
                            <select className="form-control" name="filter" onChange={this.handleChange}
                             value={this.state.filter}>
                                <option selected value="">Filter by Status</option>
                                <option>Active</option>
                                <option>Inactive</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                </div>
                <h6 style= {{color:"red"}}>{this.props.responseMessage}</h6>
                {
                    filteredAdmins.length!==0 ? filteredAdmins.map(admin=>
                    <AdminDetails admin={admin} key={admin._id}/>
                    )
                    :
                    <h2>null</h2>
                    
                }
            </div>
        </div>)
    }
}
        
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getAdmins: () => {dispatch(getAdmins())}
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        admins: state.adminUsers.admins
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AllAdmins);
```

**AdminDetails child component**

```
class AdminDetails extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showEditAdminModal: false
        };
    }

    showEditAdminModal = e => {
        this.setState({showEditAdminModal: true});
    }
    
    hideEditAdminModal = e => {
        this.setState({showEditAdminModal: false});
    }
    
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="row justify-content-center mt-3">
                <div className="col-sm-8">
                    <div className="card d-flex flex-row">
                        <div className="card-body card-body-lesspad">
                            <h5 className="card-title font-weight-bold">{`${this.props.admin.fname} ${this.props.admin.lname}`}</h5>
                            <p className="card-text font-smaller"><strong>SJSU ID: </strong>{this.props.admin.id}</p>
                            <p className="card-text font-smaller"><strong>Email ID: </strong>{this.props.admin.email}</p>
                            <p className="card-text font-smaller"><strong>Status: </strong>{this.props.admin.status}</p>
                            <p className="card-text font-smaller"><strong>Created Date: </strong>
                                {new Date(this.props.admin.createdDate).toLocaleString()}
                            </p>
                            <p className="card-text font-smaller"><strong>Updated Date: </strong>
                                {new Date(this.props.admin.updatedDate).toLocaleString()}
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-link view-details-color"
                            onClick = {this.showEditAdminModal}>
                                <i className="fas fa-edit"/> Edit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {this.state.showEditAdminModal ? 
                <EditAdminModal hideEditAdminModal={this.hideEditAdminModal}
                admin={this.props.admin}/> : null}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AdminDetails;
```

**EditAdminModal Component**

```
class EditAdminModal extends Component{
    handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        this.props.handleChange(this.props.admin._id, name, value);
    }

    handleUpdate = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState(
                { 
                    message: "",
                    loader: true
                }
            );
        this.props.updateAdmin(this.props.admin)
        .then(() => {
            this.props.hideEditAdminModal();
        })
        .catch(() => {
            this.setState({
                message: "Some Internal Error occured. Please refresh and check if the admin is updated. If not, please try again after sometime. If the problem persist, please comtact Admin."
            });
        });
    }

    options = ['Active', 'Inactive'];
    
    render() {
        return(
        <div>
            <div className="modal">
                <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h5 className="modal-title" id="itemModal">Add Admin</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <h6 style= {{color:"red"}}>{this.state.message}</h6>
                            <h6 style= {{color:"red"}}>{this.props.responseMessage}</h6>
                            
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label className="col-4">Status</label>
                                <div className="col-8">
                                    <select className="form-control" name="status" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                        {
                                            this.options.map( option => {
                                                if(option === this.props.admin.status){
                                                    return <option selected key={option}>{option}</option> ;
                                                } else {
                                                    return <option key={option}>{option}</option> ;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            )}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" onClick = {this.handleEditCancel} className="btn btn-primary btn-style" 
                                data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button onClick = {this.handleUpdate}
                                className="btn btn-primary btn-style">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        handleChange: (id, name, value) => {dispatch(adminChangeHandler(id, name, value))},
        updateAdmin: admin => dispatch(updateAdmin(admin))
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        responseMessage: state.adminUsers.createResponseMessage
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditAdminModal);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What comes to my mind right away is to store your value (status) in local component state, work with it and only when user clicks Save button you would push it to redux store.

So some parts of it would look like:

```
class EditAdminModal extends Component{
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
              status: props.admin.status;
          }
      }
      //... some other code
      onChange => (e) {
          const {value} = e;
          this.setState({status:value};
      }
      //... some other code
}
```

Then in your select you would do:

```
                                    <select className="form-control" name="status" onChange={this.onChange}> //here you use new onChange
                                    {
                                        this.options.map( option => {
                                            if(option === this.state.status){ //here you use local state
                                                return <option selected key={option}>{option}</option> ;
                                            } else {
                                                return <option key={option}>{option}</option> ;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        )}
                                </select>
```

And then in your `handleUpdate` you do:

```
this.props.updateAdmin({...this.props.admin, status:this.state.status})
```

Instead of just `this.props.updateAdming(this.props.admin)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nikita. I had an idea for this solution but won't this be anti-pattern as per facebook? As per FB 
**
Using props to generate state in getInitialState often leads to duplication of “source of truth”, i.e. where the real data is. This is because getInitialState is only invoked when the component is first created.
**

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: It is not an anti-pattern, but that’s discussable indeed - https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state It depends on the way you think about your edit component - you see it is a modal window, which kind of says “I am not the source of truth, until i am saved”. Think about it, usually in modals nothing is committed until you actually press “Save”. So from this point of view there is no conflict - modal maintain its editable content locally and then commits to single source of truth - redux in this case

Comment: Your other option if you really want to have it in redux store would be to create another reducer just for modal, and copy your values over there, edit there and then copy back.  In this case you will have one “source of truth” - which is redux, but at the same time your store will become more messy, and I believe it is less understandable

Comment: Oh and by the way, at the same site where you have read about this “anti pattern “ , it is clearly mentioned : However, it's not an anti-pattern if you make it clear that the prop is only seed data for the component's internally-controlled state. - https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Nikita, really appreciate all your answers and clarifications. This is the answer to be accepted. I tried it and this worked.